# Django aggregate field, but filtered by date

Tags: django, django-aggregation

I,m trying to annotate a sum of another model, but filtered by date.

I have the models `Employee` and `Shift`, the `Shift` one has a DecimalField called `dur`, a DateTimeField `start` and a foreign key employee.

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Shift(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    dur = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

With `Employee.objects.all().annotate(Sum('shift__dur'))` I could add the total of all shifts, but **how can I filter these shifts**, e.g. to sum just the shifts in a given date range?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the relevant models (or at least the relevant parts of these models)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The relevant parts are described in the second sentence :)

Comment: yes, but usually it is easier to work with model definitions, since these can be copied in a "sandbox Django environment"

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I understand, i've just added them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter for example with:

```
Employee.objects.filter(
    shift__start__range=('2022-01-01', '2022-01-31')
).annotate(
    total=Sum('shift__dur')
)
```

This will only show shifts for *January 2022*. Furthermore `Employee`s without any shift for *January 2022* will be filtered out.

You can also obtain data per week, for example with:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncWeek

Shift.objects.values(
    'employee_id',
    week=TruncWeek('start')
).annotate(
    total=Sum('dur')
).order_by('employee_id', 'week')
```

This will construct a `QuerySet` with:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'employee_id': 1, 'week': date(2022, 1, 3), 'total': Decimal('14.25')},
    {'employee_id': 1, 'week': date(2022, 1, 10), 'total': Decimal('13.02')},
    {'employee_id': 1, 'week': date(2022, 1, 17), 'total': Decimal('17.89')},
    {'employee_id': 2, 'week': date(2022, 1, 3), 'total': Decimal('57.3')},
    {'employee_id': 2, 'week': date(2022, 1, 17), 'total': Decimal('18.30')}
]>
```

This thus makes an aggregate per empoloyee primary key and per week (the week is truncated to start on monday), and the total lists the total of the `dur`s of the shifts. If for a given `employee_id`-`week` combination, there are no shifts, then this will *not* appear in the queryset. You thus will need to do some post-processing if you want to introduce zeros for these weeks.

Comment: Thank you! I think you ment `'2022-01-31'` instead of `'2020-01-31'` in your first example

Comment: @Jemx: aarrgghhh... Yes, thanks updated.